# initialize a static map without know the key

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members

Is it possibile to initialize a static map without know the keys?

I've a class A in which I've to use a

```
static std::map<ObjClass *, int> n_map;
```

and so I need to initialize it in this class, but due to I cannot know the content of the objects ObjClass, I got the error:

```
undefined reference to A::n_map
```

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Static class data members need to be *defined* as well as being declared. The initializer can go with either the definition for non-constant-expression members, or with the declaration for constant-expressions.

For example:

**foo.h:**

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    // declaration and initializer
    static constexpr int usageCount = 0;

    // only declaration
    static const double val1;
    static       double val2;

    // only declaration
    static std::map<int, std::string> theMap;
};
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include <foo.h>

// only definition (only required if ODR-used)
constexpr int Foo::usageCount;

// definition and initializer (initializer required, since const)
const double Foo::val1 = 1.5;

// only definition (implicitly statically-initialzied (i.e. zeroed))
double Foo::val2;

// definition and initializer
std::map<int, std::string>> Foo::theMap { { 1, "abc" }
                                        , { 2, "def" }
                                        };
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know which are the keys

Comment: @user2369478: Then populate the map later on when you know the keys...?

Comment: I want to populate the map when I will know the keys

Comment: @user2369478: Then do that!

Comment: Yes, but if I only define the map in my file.cpp without initializer I got the error above

Comment: You will not get that error if you compile the .cpp file that contains the definition of `n_map` *and also link it in your application*

Comment: @MikeKinghan How can I link it?

Comment: @user2369478 The very simplest way is this. Your source files are, say, `main.cpp`, `foo.cpp`, `bar.cpp`. Run in a terminal `g++ -o foobar main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp`. Then (unless errors) your program is compiled and linked as program `foobar` in the same directory. But if this is the problem you need to study the basics of
compiling and linking an executable: try http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html